# Pulling back symplectic structure to $TQ$ - why is a certain term (not) zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, tensors, symplectic-geometry

Let $(Q,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold, $(q^1,\ldots, q^n)$ be local coordinates in $Q$ and $(q^1,\ldots, q^n, v^1,\ldots, v^n)$ the induced tangent coordinates in $TQ$. I wanted to check that $$\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n v^j \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial q^k}\,{\rm d}q^k \wedge {\rm d}q^i = 0,$$and I'm sure it follows from the standard argument by renaming indexes and exploiting symmetries. I guess I'm just having a bad day and my brain isn't helping. Can someone help me carry this out? Thanks.

(If you want some context, this is what is left to show that if one pulls back the canonical symplectic structure from $T^*Q$ to $TQ$ via the metric, one obtains $\sum_{i,j=1}^n g_{ij}\,{\rm d}q^i \wedge {\rm d}v^j$).

---

I'll add some work since I'm starting to doubt the result (which makes me very irritated, to be honest). Define ${\rm A} \in \Omega^1(TQ)$ by $${\rm A}_{X_x}(Y_{X_x}) = \langle X_x, {\rm d}\pi_{X_x}(Y_{X_x})\rangle_x$$for all $X_x \in TQ$ and $Y_{X_x}\in T_{X_x}(TQ)$. One can write ${\rm A} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\,{\rm d}q^i+b_i\,{\rm d}v^i$. Since the coordinate fields $\partial/\partial v^i$ are vertical, we get $b_i=0$. And $$a_i(X_x) = \langle X_x, \partial/\partial q^i\big|_x\rangle_x = \sum_{j=1}^n v^i(X_x) g_{ij}(x),$$whence ${\rm A} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n (g_{ij}\circ \pi)v^j\,{\rm d}q^i$. Then $$-{\rm dA} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n(g_{ij}\circ \pi){\rm d}q^i\wedge {\rm d}v^j - {\color{blue}{\sum_{i,j,k=1}^nv^j \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial q^k}{\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}q^i}}.$$What do I do with the crap in blue? I have actually done the calculation for the Poincaré half-plane to see what was happening and I got $$-{\rm dA}= \underbrace{\frac{{\rm d}x \wedge {\rm d}v^x + {\rm d}y\wedge {\rm d}v^y}{y^2}}_{\rm expected} - \underbrace{\color{blue}{\frac{2v^x}{y^3}{\rm d}x\wedge {\rm d}y}}_{???} .$$

Comment: I observe that, in general, the 'expected expression' is not a closed 2-form, hence not a symplectic form. Moreover, at least at first sight, this 'expected term' does not seem invariant under change of coordinates $(q^i)$. So my impression is that your computation is correct. In what context was it claimed that the 'expected' expression was expected? Might it be that some specific choice of coordinates was made (for instance, normal Riemannian coordinates)?

Comment: @Jordan Good points. I have never seen this computation done in any book, so I decided to try to do it myself. I expected the 'expected' expression because of the similar situation for the standard symplectic structure in $T^*Q$: if it "does nothing", the structure induced in $TQ$ should be an anti-symmetric version of the metric itself. I guess you can just blame my wrong intuition. But normal Riemannian coordinates seem do to the trick, yes..

Comment: There might be a place where this computation is implicitly done. It is a well-known fact that the Hamiltonian flow on $T^*Q$ associated to the function $H(q,p) = \frac{1}{2} g^{ij}(q) p_i p_j$ corresponds to the geodesic flow on $TQ$, which is an instance of the parallel transport equation $\dot{v}^i(t) = - \Gamma^i_{jk}(q(t))v^j(t) \dot{q}^k(t)$.  Considering that the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^{i}_{jk}$ involve terms such as $\partial g_{ij}/\partial q^l$, the 'unexpected' term appears to me quite relevant, but I can't work out the details of its relation to parallel transport right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term I expected to vanish (five!) years ago does in fact survive. The key to explaining this lies with $$\text{the Levi-Civita connector $K\colon TTQ \to TQ$, defined by $K(\xi) = Z'(0)$,}$$ where $\xi \in T_{(x,v)}(TQ)$ and  $Z\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to TQ$ is a curve with $Z(0) = (x,v)$ and $\dot{Z}(0)=\xi$. Here, $\pi\colon TQ\to Q$ is the bundle projection and $Z'(0)$ denotes the covariant derivative at $t=0$ of $Z$ along the projected curve $\pi\circ Z\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to Q$.

Let's show that the bundle isomorphism $TQ\to T^*Q$ provided by $g$ pulls back the canonical symplectic form on $T^*Q$ to $\omega \in \Omega^2(TQ)$ given by $$\omega_{(x,v)}(\xi,\eta) = g_x({\rm d}\pi_{(x,v)}(\xi), K(\eta)) - g_x(K(\xi),{\rm d}\pi_{(x,v)}(\eta)),$$for all $\xi,\eta\in T_{(x,v)}(TQ)$.

**Step 1: Understanding $K$.**

To compute $K(\xi)$ relative to tangent coordinates $(q^1,\ldots, q^n, v^1,\ldots, v^n)$ for $TQ$, write $$\xi = \xi^{q^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}\bigg|_{(x,v)} + \xi^{v^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i}\bigg|_{(x,v)},\qquad \xi^{q^i},\xi^{v^i}\in\Bbb R,$$and $Z(t) = (q^i(t),v^i(t))$, with $\dot{q}^i(0) = \xi^{q^i}$ and $\dot{v}^i(0) = \xi^{v^i}$ for all $i$. Hence $$K(\xi) = Z'(0) = \left(\dot{v}^k(0) + \varGamma_{ij}^k(q(0))\dot{q}^i(0)v^j(0)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial q^k}\bigg|_{Z(0)} = \left(\xi^{v^k} + \varGamma_{ij}^k(x)\xi^{q^i}v^j\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial q^k}\bigg|_{(x,v)},$$where we also write $v = v^j \partial/\partial q^j |_x$ in $T_xQ$. That is, we have that $$K = ({\rm d}v^k + \varGamma_{ij}^k\, v^j\,{\rm d}q^i)\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial q^k}$$

**Step 2: pulling back the canonical symplectic form on $T^*Q$.**

We just need to use the relation $p_k = g_{k\ell}v^\ell$. Namely:$${\rm d}p_k = v^\ell\frac{\partial g_{k\ell}}{\partial q^r}{\rm d}q^r + g_{k\ell}{\rm d}v^\ell \implies {\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}p_k = v^\ell\frac{\partial g_{k\ell}}{\partial q^r}\,{\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}q^r + g_{k\ell}{\rm d}q^k\wedge{\rm d}v^\ell.$$

**Step 3: checking that this equals the proposed $\omega\in\Omega^2(TQ)$ defined in terms of $K$.**

Clearly, ${\rm d}\pi = {\rm d}q^k\otimes \partial/\partial q^k$, so distributing the terms in $$\omega = g_{k\ell} {\rm d}q^k \otimes ({\rm d}v^\ell +\varGamma_{ij}^\ell\,v^j\,{\rm d}q^i) - g_{k\ell} ({\rm d}v^k +\varGamma_{ij}^k v^j\,{\rm d}q^i)\otimes {\rm d}q^\ell$$ leads to $$\omega = g_{k\ell}{\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}v^\ell + \underbrace{\left(g_{k\ell}v^j\varGamma_{ij}^\ell{\rm d}q^k\otimes {\rm d}q^i - g_{k\ell}v^j\varGamma_{ij}^k{\rm d}q^i \otimes {\rm d}q^\ell\right)}_{(\ast)},$$meaning that the only thing left to do is to simplify $(\ast)$. By symmetry of $g$, we may switch the roles of $k$ and $\ell$ in the second term in $(\ast)$ and rename $i\mapsto r$ to obtain $$(\ast) = g_{k\ell}v^j\varGamma_{rj}^\ell{\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}q^r = \frac{v^j}{2}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial g_{kj}}{\partial q^r} + \frac{\partial g_{rk}}{\partial q^j} - \frac{\partial g_{rj}}{\partial q^k}\right)}_{(\dagger)}{\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}q^r = v^j\frac{\partial g_{kj}}{\partial q^r}{\rm d}q^k\wedge{\rm d}q^r,$$as required. We use that the second term in $(\dagger)$ is symmetric in $r$ and $k$ (so it vanishes when contracted against ${\rm d}q^k\wedge {\rm d}q^r$), while the first and third are opposites (eliminating the factor of $1/2$).

Comment: while it’s interesting to relate to the Levi-Civita connection, one doesn’t really need to. Your step 2 seems to be the key, not the connection. The symplectic form is given locally by $\omega=dp_i\wedge dq^i$, so pulling-back by the metric, we have that $p_i$ is pulled back to $g_{ij}v^j$, and so the pullback of $\omega$ is $\omega_g=d(g_{ij}v^j)\wedge dq^i=v^j\,dg_{ij}\wedge dq^i+g_{ij}dv^j\wedge dq^i$, and the first term is the one you asked about, and indeed is non-zero in general. We could of course have done this first with the tautological 1-form then taken exterior derivative.

Comment: unless I’m misunderstanding the intent of your original question…

Comment: I wanted to understand what the pulled back symplectic form looked like, but I had no idea of what the map $K$ was back then. I recently stumbled upon a paper which had the coordinate-free formula for $\omega$, but no proof (since it's certainly well-known, I was just uninformed), and I remembered this post. I'm sure there are faster ways to do it, too, but I just needed to scratch that itch to verify the formula. In hindsight, I was silly to expect that term to vanish: we're taking the derivative of something involving the metric, so of course the connection has to appear somehow.